# How to Auto fill a column using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to create a check list. How is it possible to automatically fill the "Check List Status" column using JavaScript?

What I want to do is, for example:

- If document type is equal to client agreement than the check list status should be marked automatically as yes
- if the document type is equal to blank than the status check list should automatically show up as No.

Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Asset Management Checklist Mockup</title>
 <script type='text/javascript'>

var Check List Status ='checklist';
var Client Agreement = 'client';
var Document type = 'doctype';


if ('doctype'='client')

{

document.getElementById('checklist').innerHTML = 'Yes';

} 
 </script> 
<style>

    h1 {color:blue;}
    h1 {text-align:center;}

    h2 {color:blue;
        text-align:center;
    }

    table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
padding: 15px;
}

    </style>


</head>
<body>

<h1><em>Asset Management Department</em></h1>

  <h2>Preview of automated report generation of <em>Documents Check List</em> on SharePoint.<h2> 

  <table style="width:100%">
 <caption>Asset Management</caption>
 <tr>

<th>Client Name</th>
<th>Portfolio Number</th>
<th>Portfolio Type</th>
<th id='doctype'>Document Type</th>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th id='checklist'>Check List Status</th>
  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td id='client'>Clinet Agreement</td>
<td>February</td>
<td>2001</td>
<th></th>

 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td id='email'>Email</td>
<td>February</td>
<td>2001</td>
<th></th>
 </tr>

<tr>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td id='passport'>Passport Copy</td>
<td>February</td>
<td>2001</td>
<th></th>
  </tr>

<tr>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td id='nation'>Nationality</td>
<td>February</td>
<td>2001</td>
<th></th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td od='poa'>Proof of Address</td>
<td>February</td>
<td>2001</td>
<th></th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td id='home'>Home Address</td>
<td>February</td>
<td>2001</td>
<th></th>
 </tr>

 </tr>

 <tr>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td id='pa'>Postal Address</td>
<td>February</td>
<td>2001</td>
<th></th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td id='visa'>Visa Expiry Date</td>
<td>February</td>
<td>2001</td>
<th></th>
 </tr>

<tr>
<td>Smith</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td id='family'>Family Book</td>
<td>February</td>
<td>2001</td>
<th></th>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hm, where is the content of the `<script>` tag?

Comment: I don't have any, That's what I am looking for...

Comment: Can you please suggest what JS code would be required? @JohannesJander

Comment: Unfortunately, Stackoverflow is not the right place to ask people to write your code for you. We can help find errors in your logic or your code, but you need to get started by yourself.

Comment: Oh, Ok. Let me try something myself and let's see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks @JohannesJander

Comment: I have added a bit of code in the script tag, its not working. Any ideas how to make it work? @JohannesJander

Comment: Huh? You have already accepted the answer...

Comment: Can you please help me to sort this out, the answer below is not working for some reason. The script I have written should work. Can you please have a look and check what wrong in that? @JohannesJander

Comment: But why did you accept it before checking if it works? You really should only accept answers that solve the problem.

Comment: OK, Noted. Can you please have look that code above? @JohannesJander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Javascript variable names cannot contain spaces. Things like `var Check List Status ='checklist';` will never work.
2. The expression `if ('doctype'='client')` will never be true. You are comparing two literal strings (`doctype` and `client`) that are clearly different.
3. you seemingly try to select the column with the id `checklist` and then set `innerHTML` to "yes". Because of 2. that code is never reached, but if it would, it would simply set the column header to "yes".

What you need to do is:

- iterate the table row by row (`document.querySelectorAll('#assets tr')` gives you the rows)
- for each row, find the "Document Type" cell (I have given them all the class `identifier` because classes can be used more than once per HTML page, ids not) and read its text content
- If the text content is empty, find the cell in the "Check List Status" column (I have given them all the class `check`) and set it to "No". If it is "Client Agreement", set it to "Yes".

Here's the code:

```
var clientAgreement = 'Client Agreement';

var docTable = document.getElementById('assets');
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#assets tr');

// iterate rows
for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
  // get cell for class "check"
  var checkCell = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("check")[0];
  var docTypeCell = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("identifier")[0];
  if (docTypeCell.textContent  === clientAgreement) {
    checkCell.innerHTML = "Yes";
  } else if (docTypeCell.textContent.length === 0) {
    checkCell.innerHTML = "No";
  }
}
```

And here's a [JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/hepajidadi/edit?html,js,output) that also contains the edited HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This will work;

```
function init(){
    var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].children[1].children;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < trs.length; i += 1) {
        if (trs[i].children[3].innerHTML.indexOf('Clinet Agreement') > -1) {
            trs[i].children[6].innerHTML = 'yes';
        }
    }
}
```

if you call it onload (`<body onload="init();">`) but you should add id and class attributes to your HTML to make it referenceable from JavaScript and thus more robust. Also your table needs a tbody tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user1133275

Comment: I have added a bit of code in the script tag, its not working. Any ideas how to make it work?  @user1133275

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibAsghar the answer is updated to include an onload example.